# Authenticating Firebase Admin SDK on GCE VM with Application Default Credentials

Tags: node.js, google-compute-engine, firebase-admin, google-iam

I can't seem to authenticate with the Firebase Admin SDK on a GCE VM. With

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
  databaseURL: `https://${PROJECT_ID}-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com`,
});
```

my app indicates

```
Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
```

From what I can tell, this is because the scopes [are missing on the Application Default Credentials](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#set-scopes-for-realtime-database-auth)? Isn't this supposed to be configured automatically?

I've verified that if I take the compute service account, generate a json key, and then pass it to the admin sdk manually everything works, so I'm not clear why it doesn't correctly fetch the credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there's a checkbox that needs to be checked when creating the instance

[image]